# python float to c++ double using BOOST

Tags: python, c++, boost

I am new to python c++ interface. I have a dictionary of list and float variables  in a python file. Am extracting this python objects into c++ variables. Am able to extract the lists into the vector variables. but am unable to do the same for float type.

this is my dict in dict.py

```
ATM__INTERPOLATION_CUBE = {
   "xOrigin": xOrigin,

   "yOrigin": yOrigin,

    "zOrigin": zOrigin,

    "xEnd"   : xEnd,

    "yEnd"   : yEnd,

    "zEnd"   : zEnd,

    "point_xdensity":point_xdensity,

    "point_ydensity":point_ydensity,

    "point_zdensity":point_zdensity,

    "short_Space_x" : 0.25,

    "short_Space_y" : 0.25,

    "short_Space_z" : 0.25}

ATM__TYPE = "3D_CUBE"
```

In my c++ script, I create an object myconfig of python dict type.

> `python::dict myconfig = ctl->scanConfig("ATM__INTERPOLATION_CUBE", python::dict(), True);`

then I create a python list and store each list into a new python list

>

```
python::list xOrigin_list(myconfig["xOrigin"]);
>python::list yOrigin_list(myconfig["yOrigin"]);
```

then I extract the python list into my c++ vector variable using loop

```
> for(init;condt;incr)
   > xOrigin.push_back(python::extract <double>(xOrigin_list[i]));
   > yOrigin.push_back(python::extract<double>(yOrigin_list[i]));
```

but the above procedure doesnt work for float or long :(

> 

```
python::long short_Space_x_fl(myconfig["short_Space_x"]);

> short_Space_x = python::extract<double>(short_Space_x_fl);
```

it gives me an error. can someone please tell me how to extract the value of type float/long from python and store in c++ double variable?

```
var.cc:18:11: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘long’
```

thanks in advance

Comment: There's a slight possibility that providing the actual error message might be of some meager value in determining how to resolve your issue. Otherwise, we're just guessing...

Comment: ^^ to be precise, the python::long is not being interpreted as a python long object. instead it is considering it as a C++ long data type. """"
var.cc:18:11: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘long’
"""""
I can see why I get this error, as the compiler is unable to differentiate between C++ long and python long, but am unable to find a solution to it

Comment: I know almost nothing about Boost.Python but, looking at the documentation, I think what you want to use is [`python::long_`](http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/v2/long.html#long_-spec)(Notice the underscore).

Comment: ^^ cv_and_he ^kudos.. your answer was right. It worked. Thank you. I wish I could give you a +1

Comment: I guess i was wrong. using long, it is being considered as 0L which is nothing but int. hence my answer is wrong. I read the documentation in BOOST LIb for python extract.
It is straight forward to extract float int long 
>>>    double xx = python::extract<double>(myconfig["short_Space_x"])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only when a list is to be extracted into a vector the above usage works. But for extracting a single data (int, float, long) the extraction syntax is straight forward,

```
double var_name = python::extract<double>(python_dict_obj["python_key"]);
```

this will store the float value in dictionary at the given key into the variable of c++